# Current view is adding on my window agan and again on tapping the custom tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have made a custom tab bar in my application ...On clicking the same tab bar button again the view adds ...Please tell me how to manage the view so that  if a view is on window and if i presses the tab bar again the view shouldnt be added or loaded again.

Comment: Please post the code that creates the views.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether viewcontroller is nil or not. if viewcontroller is nil then add new one else simpally popToRootViewController. You can find many tab bar implementation, Please refer below link

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/TabBarAnimation

https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar

https://github.com/i300/TweetBotTabBar